# Is this a liquid?

Tags: hand-luggage

I thought the day when I can't decide whether something is a liquid will never come but there's a first for everything. We all know there are very odd rules about liquids to the extent of certain sausages being liquids. With that said, http://www.clinique.ca/product/13561/44036/holiday-2016/indulge-in-colour-set is this a liquid or can I carry this on? Mind you, I have no idea what it is, I bought it as a gift to my SIL.

Comment: Please let us know how many days (weeks, years) it takes for SIL to stop laughing, as this becomes family legend :-)

Comment: I think she'd have as much clue recognizing a security hole in a web app as I do with recognizing whether it's powder or grease... we all have our strengths and weaknesses.

Comment: As would I... LMAOROTF, and we do; yours is also being gift-appropriate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The item pictured doesn't appear to be liquid. First, it isn't liquid, and it isn't in a container for liquid. Instead it looks like powdered makeup. You can bring [as much of that as you want](https://apps.tsa.dhs.gov/mytsa/cib_results.aspx?search=makeup), at least in the USA.

Comment: Thanks for saving my poor XS Aviator a trip in the hold :) For all I knew it could've greasepaint or somesuch.